# How to extract elements in list into numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing

So I'm taking input from the user for the number of images to display and then I run a for loop to input the image id for each image. I store the image id in a list.

Now I want to use the elements(image ids) in the list in a numpy array. I am using the VGG16 model to do some image processing and want to test the model on the image ids specified by the user.

Here is the code:

```
i = int(input("\nEnter no. of images you want to view: "))
img_no_=[]
for j in range(i):
  img_no_.append(int(input("Enter image number (b/w 1-50): ")))

to_explain = X[[img_no_]]
```

I keep getting the error:

```
Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a different result.
```

and hence tried to save the image id list as a tuple and a numpy array but I got the same error on both cases.

```
to_ = numpy.asarray(img_no_)  
#print(to_explain)
#to_1 = tuple(img_no_)
to_explain = X[[tuple(to_)]]
```

If you could help me not get this error or show me a different approach that satisfies the requirement, that would be great.

For example- img_no_ = [12,24,36] and now I want to_explain = X[[12,24,36]] (X is a tensor)

Edit: The ')]]' was a typo

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem here is, `X[to_]` should work just fine (Assuming `X` is a numpy array)

Comment: Need to have 'X[ [ ] ]' as it is the dimension of VGG model. If I use only X[ ], I get the following ValueError

ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 1, 224, 224, 3) for Tensor 'input_1:0', which has shape '(?, 224, 224, 3)'

Comment: you should specify these things in the quesion, we cant get that your `X` is a tensor

Comment: Yes, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what 'X' is but I think you just want to pass the list to be the first element of a different list?

```
to_explain=X[img_no_]
```

should work fine. I think possibly your original error is due to the mixing of square and normal brackets?

Comment: No, the brackets are fine because X is the numpy array I am feeding to the VGG16 model and it is of the dimensions (50,224,224,3)

Comment: It is really not clear what you are trying to do. Please post a full example.

Comment: Need to have 'X[ [ ] ]' as it is the dimension of VGG model. If I use only X[ ], I get the following ValueError ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 1, 224, 224, 3) for Tensor 'input_1:0', which has shape '(?, 224, 224, 3)'